# Setting String arrays equal to each other

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to set two String[] equal to each other while one has been returned (method has been returned containing a String[])?

Example:

- Returned array>>>>>>>>>>>Array I want set equal to the returned array

  authorArray[x].getAuthor() == authorArray[x]

Comment: "while one has been returned?" what does that mean?

Comment: a method that has been returned, containing an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make your code a little more readable by using `Arrays.copyOf()`:

```
destination = Arrays.copyOf(source,source.length);
```

Internally, this does the same thing, but it's a little clearer.

Comment: That could also be written `destination = source.clone();`. However, I don't *think* it's what OP wants. The question isn't clear, but I think OP's point was that the destination array already exists.

Comment: @Boann What? This assumes `destination` already exists. Also there is no `.clone()` for arrays.

Comment: ‎@AnubianNoob No, this creates a new array, regardless of whether the destination array was already allocated or not. For example this technique is of no use if one wants to modify an array returned by a method: `methodThatReturnsAnArray() = Arrays.copyOf(source, source.length);` does not compile, whereas `System.arraycopy(source, 0, methodThatReturnsAnArray(), 0, source.length);` works. And `clone()` does exist for arrays; see [JLS § 10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7).

Comment: `methodThatReturnsAnArray() = _anything_` does not compile.  Not clear what you are trying to say here.

Comment: @user949300 Obviously you could write `String[] destination = methodThatReturnsAnArray();
destination = Arrays.copyOf(source, source.length);` but that isn't useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-), which you can use to copy the contents of one array into another:

```
String[] source = /* ... the new data ... */;
String[] destination = /* ... array returned by getAuthor() ... */;

System.arraycopy(source, 0, destination, 0, source.length);
```

This assumes that the destination array already exists (is non-null), and has the same length.

Comment: Though your point is valid, and in a few cases (huge arrays) `arraycopy()` is appropriate, in general, your assumption is a good reason to use `Arrays.copyOf()` instead.  Way simpler and less error prone.

Comment: @user949300 The point is that `authorArray[x].getAuthor() == authorArray[x]` in the question, although it's not grammatical, implies that OP wants to modify an array returned by a method. `Arrays.copyOf` won't do that.